# Ubuntu doesn't run the program which is added to the startup

Tags: startup, sshfs

I have to re-login to make it works, and do it every time I turn on my computer.

This is the command which I have added to the startup.
[image]

Comment: I really can't read anything on that images you posted so what is the program you're trying to add to the startup

Comment: -----sshfs-----

Comment: how do you authenticate? What output do you get from the running program?

Comment: I have tried it through the terminal, and everything works fine, but it doesn't work when the OS starts up after I add "/usr/bin/sshfs -p <portNumber> <username>@<PC-Name>:<path_of_my_4FPC> <path_of_HTPC>" to autostart.